# Visual studio 2022 - freezes when opening javascript files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

upgraded from 2019 to 2022.

opened a previous MVC project all builds and loads and runs fine and all files open ok in the editor.

BUT try to open ANY JS files you get this and it just sits there doing nothing else

[image]

Comment: Have you find any fix? 
I'm also facing the same issue!

Comment: only in that if you leave it long enough to finally opens - or go back to 2019 :-)

Comment: Hey thanks, will try 2019 version!

Answer (score 4):

according to this link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/search-in-minified-cssjs-files-freezes-visual-stud/1227023

A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.

Answer (score 4):

1- Hide All Excluded Files
**screenshot**
[image]

2- Open Javascript File